# Syntax for math equation is not correct

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, math, double, color-space

I'm trying to convert XYZ values to LAB* using the formula available [here](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=07#text7).

The problem is, when I go through the formula - the output for the three variables var_X,var_Y and var_Z is always 1.00.

If I put values using into [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pow%280.345393,%20%28%201/3%20%29%29;%20%20%20) I actually get the (presumably) correct output (the example in the link is the input of var_Z shown in the logs at the bottom of this question).

Could you help me find where I've gone wrong?

Here's my code:

```
-(NSArray*)convertXYZtoLABSpaceWithLABArray:(NSArray*)labArray{
    double var_X = [[labArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue] /  95.047;
    double var_Y = [[labArray objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue] /  100.000;
    double var_Z = [[labArray objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue] /  108.883;

    NSLog(@"convertXYZtoLAB... var_X: %f var_Y: %f var_Z: %f", var_X, var_Y, var_Z);

    if ( var_X > 0.008856 ){
        var_X = pow(var_X, ( 1/3 ));   
    }else{                    
        var_X = ( 7.787 * var_X ) + ( 16 / 116 );
    }

    if ( var_Y > 0.008856 ){
        var_Y = pow(var_Y, ( 1/3 ));   
    }else{
        var_Y = ( 7.787 * var_Y ) + ( 16 / 116 );   
    }

    if ( var_Z > 0.008856 ){
        var_Z = pow(var_Z, ( 1/3 ));   
    }else{
        var_Z = ( 7.787 * var_Z ) + ( 16 / 116 );   
    }

    NSLog(@"convertXYZtoLAB... var_X: %f var_Y: %f var_Z: %f", var_X, var_Y, var_Z);

    NSNumber *l,*a,*b;

    l = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:( 116 * var_Y ) - 16];
    a = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:500 * ( var_X - var_Y )];
    b = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:200 * ( var_Y - var_Z )];

    return([NSArray arrayWithObjects:l,a,b, nil]);

}
```

And here is the input/output of the formula at the two log points in the method:

```
convertXYZtoLAB... var_X: 0.345393 var_Y: 0.502066 var_Z: 0.308145
convertXYZtoLAB... var_X: 1.000000 var_Y: 1.000000 var_Z: 1.000000
```

Comment: You may want to try [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably getting integer division instead of floating point division.  Try `1.0/3` instead of `1/3`, etc.  `1/3` rounds down to zero in integer math.

Comment: All three are taken to the 0th power, which is 1.0.